# Input user return function

Tags: python, list, return, series

The question I'm trying to complete is:

The user or grader will input a key of the data dictionary. Print out the last element of the list associated with that key

data = {

"series1": [0,2,4,6,8,10],

}

sample input:

series1

10

I've tried these solutions based on previously asked questions but neither works:

```
data = {

  "series1": [0,2,4,6,8,10],

}



(series1[-1]) = input('series1')
```

and this:

```
data = {
  "series1": [0,2,4,6,8,10],
}

if input: "series1"

  return: (series1[-1])

else:

  print ('error')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "but neither works" What happens when you run your code. What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: I would like the program to return the same function as the sample does.

Comment: Could you give an example of a code with correct punctuation that may be able to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm new to coding and I'm trying to learn as I go.

Comment: Can you say more about the problem with the solution posted by quamrana that I assume you downvoted?

Comment: Didn't downvote, I can't until I 15 reputation record. The program response is: NameError: name 'series1' is not defined

Comment: @twelsh97--do you only have the code from the answer along with the definition of data?  If so, don't see how you're getting a NameError.  A key error is possible if you enter something other than than `'series1', 'series2' or 'series3'` but not NameError.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using @quamrana's solution. I think it was an error on Repl's part. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean this:

```
while True:
    print(data[input()][-1])
```

Comment: It did not take that as a solution unfortunately.

Comment: What is the ‘it’?

Comment: NameError: name 'series1' is not defined